# xcode 11.3 - download simulator runtime > 13.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and I need to stay on this version.

My simulator runtimes only go up to 13.2.  It actually has 13.3 as well but doesn't show in this list.  Is there a way to get newer versions like 13.4 or 13.5 without upgrading the xcode version?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get newer versions like 13.4 or 13.5?

Yes, there is:

[image]

Just update to the latest Xcode and there they are.

Comment: I updated my question to note - without upgrading the xcode version.

Comment: Then no there’s no way. Basically you ask how to do something and rule out the answer.